# How do I make a back button with a custom image accessible?

Tags: ios, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I have a custom back image:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:myImage
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

However this causes (what I presume is a bug) where the item is no longer accessible:

- `isAccessibilityElement = NO`
- `accessibilityLabel = nil`
- Therefore not selectable with voice over

I want to set it back to normal, but the following does not work:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton;
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.accessibilityLabel = ROOLocalised_Back;
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the issue here is that the accessibilityElement is set to NO, but anyway, if that is the case, I'd try adding the following line:

What if you try:

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setAccessibilityElementsHidden:NO];
```